# Why is '\xff' not being recognized?

Tags: c

I know that 0xff can have different representations depending on what the variable type is. Like -1 for signed (chars/ints(?)) and 255 for unsigned chars.

But I am using the implementation-independent type of uint8_t and i've made sure that 0xff is infact inside the structure I am iterating across. Here is the code:

```
struct pkt {
    uint8_t msg[8];
};

void main(int argc, char **argv) {
    ...

    struct pkt packet;
    memset(&packet, 0, sizeof packet);
    strcpy(packet.msg, "hello");
    packet.msg[strlen("hello")] = '\xff';

    crypt(&packet, argv[1]);    

    ...
}

void crypt(struct pkt *packet, unsigned char *key) {
    int size = msglen(packet->msg);

    ...
}

int msglen(uint8_t *msg) {
    int i = 0;
    while(*(msg++) != '\xff') {
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}
```

I've looked into the structure, and packet.msg[5] is indeed set to 0xff. But the while loop goes into an infinite loop, like it never discovered 0xff.

Values such as 0x7f works. I haven't tried 0x80 but I suspect it probably won't work if 0xff doesn't. It probably has something to do with the signness, but I just cant't see where the problem is supposed to come from.

Thanks.

EDIT: For me, it doesn't matter if I use 0x7f or 0xff. But I would just like to know what is preventing me from detecting 0xff.

Comment: `while(*(msg++) != (uint8_t)'\xff') {`

Comment: `main` returns `int`, not `void`.

Comment: And if you enable `-Wall -Wextra`, you'll see a "comparison between signed and unsigned" warning on the line in question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have an unsigned, you can't use character literals.

'\xff' is -1, not 255, because the a character literal is signed.

The while condition is always true. If you are unsigned you should be using numbers only: 0 to 255, or casting characters you know are <128 to unsigned.

Comment: `'\xff'` is a character constant, not a string literal. String literals have no signedness; they represent arrays. Type `char` may be either signed or unsigned, depending on the implementation. If plain `char` is unsigned, then `'\xff'` has the value 255 of type `int`. If plain `char` is signed, the wording of the standard is unclear (at least to me).

Comment: While the general nature of the answer is in the right direction, there are errors in the statements. -1 from me.

Comment: Yes - I meant value literal not string literal. Keith what do you mean by 'they represent arrays'. Also the C standard says they have to be ints (that is signed ints), it says nothing about signed or unsigned chars.

Answer (score 4):

`\xff` is a character constant. It's of type `int`, not `char` (this is one way in which C differs from C++), but its value depends on whether plain `char` is signed or unsigned, which is implementation-defined.

The wording in the C standard is:

> The hexadecimal digits that follow the backslash and the letter **`x`** in a
>   hexadecimal escape sequence are taken to be part of the construction
>   of a single character for an integer character constant or of a single
>   wide character for a wide character constant. The numerical value of
>   the hexadecimal integer so formed specifies the value of the desired
>   character or wide character.

If plain `char` is unsigned, then `'\xff'` is equivalent to `0xff` or `255`; it's of type `int` and has the value `255`.

If plain `char` is signed, then `'\xff'` specifies a value that's outside the range of `char` (assuming that `char` is 8 bits). The wording of the standard isn't 100% clear to me, but at least with gcc the value of `'\xff'` is `-1`.

Just use an integer constant `0xff` rather than a character constant `\xff'`. `0xff` is of type `int` and is guaranteed to have the value `255`, which is what you want.

Answer (score 2):

> I know that 0xff can have different representations depending on what the variable type is. Like -1 for signed (chars/ints(?)) and 255 for unsigned chars.

This needs some explanation. The integer literal `0xFF` in a C program always means `255`. If you assign this to a type for which `255` is out of range, e.g. a `signed char` then the behaviour is implementation-defined.   Typically on 2's complement systems this is defined as assigning the value `-1`.

Character literals have different rules to integer literals. The character literal `'\xff'` must be a value that can sit in a `char`. You appear to have signed `char`, so it's implementation-defined what happens here, but again the most common behaviour is that this gets value `-1`. Note that character literals actually have type `int` despite the fact that they must have values representable by `char`.

In the line `packet.msg[strlen("hello")] = '\xff';` , you try to assign `(int)-1` to a `uint8_t`. This is out of range, but the behaviour is well-defined for out-of-range assignment to signed types, so the value you get is `-1 (mod 256)` which is `255`.

Finally, when using the `==` operator (and most operators), the values are promoted to `int` if they were not already int. The 8-bit int `255` is promoted to `(int)255`, and you compare this against `(int)-1`, and they differ.

To solve this , change your comparison to have either `0xFF`, or `(uint8_t)'\xFF'`.